# StackExchange API occasionally sends question without requested fields

Tags: bug, api

I'm using the API to make queries like this one:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?filter=%21-%2Af%286rkvD-tO&tagged=php&fromdate=1427846400&todate=1430438400&page=60&pagesize=100&key=BmopG%29d9Thccirg4e%29CjOw%28%28&site=stackoverflow

Normally each question has a `body_markdown` property, but now and then I get a question that doesn't have it. For example the question 29813692 below. If I check it on StackOverflow though, the question is fine with a body - [PHP query keeps failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813692)

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

[image]

Comment: It's not just the API: the revision history of that post is... [lacking](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29813692/revisions). A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813692/php-query-keeps-failing#comment47755034_29813692) hints at the reason: the post was redacted to remove the user's credentials. Still a bug, probably.

Comment: Oh that's right. The question body might be missing on purpose then, so that scripts don't automatically fetch his database credentials along with the rest of the question. Indeed still seems to be a bug though, since the question now no longer includes his credentials.

Comment: Is "markdown_body" different from "body_markdown"?

Comment: @Will, I meant "body_markdown" actually, I've updated the question.

Comment: Isn't it in there?  Clicked the link and it had a bunch of 'em in there (sorry, lots of text, unknown format, did a text search).  Or does it go missing randomly?

Comment: Yes it's just one now and then, very rarely. If you search for "29813692" on the API link I've provided you'll see it's missing for that particular question.